border isn't aligned with borderbox:box-sizing
I have a problem with a contact form that I inserted in a HTML file. When I use the instruction borderbox: box-sizing in my css file the contact form is perfectly aligned but throughout the page the border is offset. I can't figure out how to fix the case.
Here the code in the file html
<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="country">Country</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <select id="country" name="country">
          <option value="australia">Australia</option>
          <option value="canada">Canada</option>
          <option value="usa">USA</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>


Here the file css
/* File css */

/* Reset.css */
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, Fdd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {margin: 0;padding: 0;border: 0;font-size: 100%;vertical-align: baseline;}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {display: block;}
blockquote, q { quotes: none; }
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after { content: ""; content: none; }
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
html {overflow-y: scroll; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }

/*** General ***/
body {color: #666;font: 16px/28px;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;background: #e2e2e0;}

    /* Typography */
    a           {color: #000;text-decoration: none;-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;}
    a:hover     {color: #21aabd;}
    a:active    {outline: none;}
    p, dl, hr, h1, h2, h3,
    ol, ul, dd, pre, table, fieldset {margin-bottom: 20px;}
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;}
    h1          {font-size: 32px;}
    h2          {font-size: 28px;}
    h3          {font-size: 26px;letter-spacing: -1px;}
    h4          {font-size: 21px;margin-bottom: 15px;}
    h5          {font-size: 18px;}
    h6          {font-weight: normal;font-size: 16px;}
    
    /* Structure */
    #wrapper        {width: 960px;margin: 0 auto;background:#fff;}
    #header         {width: 920px;float:left;padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px; background:seagreen;} 
    #mainmenu       {width: 100%;float:left;background: #888}
    #main           {width: 920px;float:left;padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;}
    #content        {width: 620px;float:left;}
    #sidebar        {width: 270px;float:right;}
    #footer         {width: 920px;float:left;padding: 30px 20px 10px 20px;background:seagreen;}


/*** Header ***/
#site-title a           {font-family: oswald; font-weight: 400; font-size:30px; text-transform:uppercase;float: left;color:#fff;}
#site-title a:hover     {background: none;}

/*** Google Maps ***/
.maps {position: relative; padding-bottom: 40%; padding-top: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;}
.maps iframe {position: absolute; top:0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}

/*** Menu ***/
#mainmenu ul      {margin: 0px 0 0px 0px;float:left;width:100%; list-style: none;}
#mainmenu ul li   {float: left;margin: 0 0px 0 0;position: relative;}
#mainmenu a       {color: #fff; display: block;font: 14px;padding: 14px 20px;font-family: oswald; text-transform:uppercase;}
#mainmenu a:hover {background:#666;}
    
    
    /* Button Responsive Menu*/
    .btn-responsive-menu{display: none;float: right;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;margin:  -15px 20px 0 0;color: #ffffff;text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);background:#333;-webkit-border-radius: 4px;-moz-border-radius: 4px;border-radius: 4px;}
    .icon-bar           {display: block;width: 18px;height: 2px;margin:5px;background-color: #f5f5f5;-webkit-border-radius: 1px;-moz-border-radius: 1px;border-radius: 1px;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);}
    .show{display:block!important}

/*** Contact Form ***/

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=text], select, textarea {width: 100%; padding: 12px; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 4px; resize: vertical;}
  
  label {
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
  }

 
  
  input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
  }
    
      
      .container {
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      
      .col-25 {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
        margin-top: 6px;
      }
      
      .col-75 {
        
        float: left;
        width: 75%;
        margin-top: 6px;
      }
      
      /* Clear floats after the columns */
      .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
      }
      
      /* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
      @media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
        .col-25, .col-75, input[type=submit] {
          width: 100%;
          margin-top: 0;
        }
      } 
    



    
/*** Post ***/
.post                   {padding: 0px 0 0px 0;}


    /* Post title */
    .post .entry-title  {margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: -4px;}
    .post .entry-title a{display: block;font-size: 38px;line-height:40px;font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: -1px;}
    .post .entry-content{line-height:25px;}
    .index-thumb        {width:100%;height:auto;margin-bottom:10px;}
    
    hr{border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-right:none;margin:25px 0 20px 0;}
        

/*** Sidebar ***/
#sidebar {}

    /* Lists in widgets */
    .widget h3          {}
    .widget li          {line-height: 35px;list-style-type:none}


/*** Footer ***/
#footer                 {color: #fff;}
#footer a               {font: 14px;}


/*** Misc ***/ 
.alignleft      {margin: 0 20px 20px 0;}
.alignright     {margin: 0 0 20px 20px;}
.clear      {clear: both;}
.sep        {padding: 0 5px;}
.hide       {display: none;}
.alert {
  background-color: #fef9c7;
  border-color: #fcdd4a;
  color: #3b3601;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  padding: 10px 14px;margin:0;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

I post two images of my problem


The contact form is aligned but the other elements aren't aligned with the border.
If I try to deleted the code
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

the contact form text input isn't aligned but the other elements in the page html are ok.

Hi! I found a solution. I inserted the instruction box-sizing: border.box; inside this instruction in the css file:
input[type=text], select, textarea {width: 100%; padding: 12px; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 4px; resize: vertical;}
